# In VS Code can I debug runs remotely if server is not directly accessible from the desktop?

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger, hpc, vscode-remote

I am not a user of VS Code user, but many of my colleagues are. The context of my question is bare-metal clusters. Typically, there is only an SSH access to a login node, but no direct access to work/compute nodes which may have specialised hardware and are controlled with workflow management suites like LSF or Slurm. Finally, there's often limited software available on compute nodes due to deployment procedures. Complex software stacks can be maintained but most of the time have to be compiled from scratch. All installations I know are Linux based but users come from all sorts of OSes out there.

I'd like ask how to configure VS Code to enable a user to take advantage of debugging interface in VS Code, but remotely control/inspect execution on a randomly allocated compute node. I feel this should be technically possible with Debug Adapter Protocol and some SSH local/remote port forwarding skulduggery. For the sake of example, a solution for C would be ideal.

Would appreciate any guidance. Debugging parallel runs is key so any guidance on MPI or CUDA would be appreciated.